# Exceptions/OS Errors installing graphlab

Tags: permissions, python

I've been trying to install graphlab on my machine, and keep running into errors.  I used the following command:

pip install graphlab-create

and it then runs through most of the install, but then barfs up the following list of exceptions and errors:

```
Found existing installation: boto 2.38.0
    DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (boto) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
    Uninstalling boto-2.38.0:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/catman/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 211, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/catman/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 311, in run
    root=options.root_path,
  File "/home/catman/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 640, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/home/catman/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 716, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/home/catman/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 125, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/home/catman/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 315, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/home/catman/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 303, in move
    os.unlink(src)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/catman/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto-2.38.0-py2.7.egg-info'
```

Please help!  I'm not sure if the existing installation of boto is a problem or not as well, so I included that.  I appreciate any advice.

Edit:

As requested by A.B. I've added the following information:

```
File: ‘/home/catman/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto-2.38.0-py2.7.egg-info’
  Size: 8590        Blocks: 24         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 802h/2050d  Inode: 25827741    Links: 2
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2015-11-05 12:51:31.373372011 +0700
Modify: 2015-04-24 04:06:03.000000000 +0700
Change: 2015-11-05 09:39:58.559261464 +0700
 Birth: -
```

Comment: As you can read at the end of the error message, you have a "Permission denied". [EDIT] your question and add the output of `stat /home/catman/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto-2.38.0-py2.7.egg-info`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the output of `stat /home/catman/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto-2.38.0-py2.7.egg-info`, only `root` has the necessary access rights.

Correct the wrong owner and group:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /home/catman/anaconda2
```

Comment: A.B. this worked perfectly, thanks so much for taking the time to help me out.  I'm a complete n00b to Linux/Ubuntu, and I know permissions problems are rookie mistakes.  I appreciate the help, and will attempt to pay it forward as I get better at Linux and Python.

Comment: I assume, you have installed Anaconda with `sudo`. That's not necessary if you install Anaconda in your home folder.

Comment: So does installing with 'sudo' automatically set 'root' as the owner?  I was under the impression that I always had to install with 'sudo'.

Comment: You need only sudo for an installation, if the target of the installation isn't your home folder. During the installation of Anaconda, the installer asks you, where to install. Default is `/home/$USER/anaconda`. Changing this path to e.g. `/opt/anaconda` needs sudo for the installation.

Comment: Interesting.  I certainly used sudo for the installation, but chose the default folder as you've mentioned.  If I had not used sudo, then, the permissions would have been set for the current user?

Comment: Yes, that's right.